# FBX Converter from the Mac terminal?

Tags: export, osx

I need to convert a batch of .obj models to .fbx

I'm using Autodesk 2013 FBX Converter GUI. Is it possible to do it from the terminal? I haven't been able to find much.

I'm writing a Blender script to do some changes to a model then automatically export that model to both .obj and .fbx

The .obj export works like a charm, but the blender fbx exporter has some problems.

1. It can't embed all the media so I need to relink textures
2. The scale/rotation is off

But, I found that if I use the fbx converter on the .obj model I exported it looks great, so I was wondering if I could automate that conversion from my addon.

Comment: Yes it is sorry for the confusion. I'm writing a blender script to do some changes to a model then automatically export that model to both .obj and .fbx

The .obj export works like a charm, but the blender fbx exporter has some problems.
1) It can't embed all the media so I need to relink textures
2) The scale/rotation is off

But, I found that if I use the fbx converter on the .obj model I exported it looks great, so I was wondering if I could automate that conversion from my addon.

Comment: @RobertCornwall There are the same `path_mode` options, so this should work for both: https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.export_scene.html#bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx, right?

Answer (score 2):

You won't get any help using the Autodesk converter here, but if you are asking whether you can use blender to do the conversions, then the answer might be yes. Blender is able to import and export both obj and fbx files, you will need to do some tests to see if the models you have are handled correctly.

Blender has a python interpreter built into it, you can use blender's [python console](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/python_console.html) to enter python commands to do your conversion. You can also open a text file in blender's [text editor](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/text_editor.html) and run it as a python script.

You could also start blender in the [terminal](https://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/command_line/introduction.html#mac-osx) and have it act as an [interactive python console](https://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#python-options) in the terminal without using blender's gui.

The commands you want to use to convert your models are [`bpy.ops.import_scene.obj()`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.import_scene.html#bpy.ops.import_scene.obj) and [`bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx()`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.export_scene.html#bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx)

You could start with a script like

```
import bpy
import os

src_dir = '/Users/name/Desktop/obj_files'
dest_dir = '/Users/name/Desktop/fbx_files'

for f in os.listdir(src_dir):
    # delete all existing objects
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.object.delete()
    bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=os.path.join(src_dir,f))
    bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=os.path.join(dest_dir,f))
```